# Windows 7 File Associations not working

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, file-association

Clean Windows 7 Install.

Start - Default Programs - File Associations available.
Install Office 97 Access only.

`Start - Default Programs - File Associations` causes Windows Explorer to Crash.

Details show `OLE32.DLL`

Would love some help on this.  Sounds like a similar problem detailed in Microsoft KB978591

Answer (score 1):

That's because it isn't fully [compatible with Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Software&p=Microsoft%20Office%2097&v=Microsoft&uid=&l=en&pf=0&pi=0&s=access%2097&os=64-bit). I wouldn't expect it to be either since it's 14 years old :)

Comment: I understand, but I only have one Access DB and can't justify a new version just for this.  Since a similar problem was FIXED, I was hoping for the same here.

Comment: Could you perhaps port it to OpenOffice?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article:

> http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/4f729cea-aafb-4d4a-b863-705a13de486a

It offers some possible solutions...

Personally, I have installed Office 1997 applications on an external hard drive, and they will run on any computer that I plug into with no issues...for what it's worth...